# Java - Универсальный путь к файлу

Tags: java, csv, path

У меня есть файл cars.csv,  как задать универсальный путь к этому файлу, чтобы с каждого компьютера компилятор его видел? 
Использовал такой способ:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile()
```

Но хочу узнать существует ли что-то практичнее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно используется специальная директория, называется ресурсы

[пример использования](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

Если создается мавен проект, то структура проекта уже будет содержать директории для тестов и ресурсов.

Второй вариант, задавать относительный путь, относительно точки вызова программы:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/someFile.csv");
```